# Confusion on phase diagrams of ODES in the complex plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working through some simple complex differential equations to try to get a better understanding of them. The textbook I'm using has given me the following diff-eq:
$$
z' = z^2 - 1
$$
I have solved it using the techniques I'm familiar with, and I got:
$$
z = \frac{1-Ce^{2t}}{Ce^{2t}+1}
$$
Where $C \in \mathbb{C}$.
How would I draw the phase diagram for this? It seems that I would need some assumptions on the sign of $Re(C) \text{ and }  Im(C)$? Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $z= x+i y$ we have

$$
\dot x+ i\dot y = (x+i y)^2-1\Rightarrow \cases{\dot x = x^2-y^2-1\\ \dot y = 2 x y}
$$

[image]

In red the orbit associated to the initial conditions $z(0) = 1+0.2 i$